# Program stops when inputting data for the scanf_s

Tags: c, string, struct

Program:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"
//#include "iostream"
const int IDLEN = 10;
const int POLARITYLEN = 3;
const int MAXSTOCKITEMS = 10;
struct TransistorRec {
    char manufacturersID[IDLEN + 1];
    char polarity[POLARITYLEN + 1];
    float power;
    float gain;
    int stock;
};
typedef struct TransistorRec Transistor;
struct StockRec{
    int size;
    Transistor stocklist[MAXSTOCKITEMS];
};
typedef struct StockRec Stock;
int main()
{
    int total, i;
    struct TransistorRec a[10];
    char x, y;
    printf("How many transistors: ");
    scanf_s("%i", &total);
    if (total >MAXSTOCKITEMS){
        printf("too much!! repeat");
        scanf_s("%i\n", &total);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < total; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter manufacturer's ID of transistor:");
        scanf_s("%s",a[i].manufacturersID);
        printf("Enter polarity of transistor: ");
        scanf_s("%s",a[i].polarity);
        printf("Enter power of transistor: ");
        scanf_s("%f",a[i].power);
        printf("Enter gain of transistor: ");
        scanf_s("%f",a[i].gain);
        printf("Enter current stock of transistor: ");
        scanf_s("%i",a[i].stock);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My assignment:

> Write a C function that reads from the user (keyboard) the information about the transistors in stock,
>   and stores this information in the Stock structure. A sample set of input data (manufacturer’s ID,
>   polarity, maximum power, current gain, number in stock) is:
>   2N2222 NPN 0.5 75 23
>   BC559 PNP 0.5 125 7
>   TIP31B NPN 40.0 20 11

Problem:
When i input my values(strings) through `scanf_s` to a structure , the program will stop.

Comment: Go away and write it yourself.

Comment: my x used to be a[i].manufacturersID

Comment: and y are a[i].polarity, i just forget to change back,

Comment: but my code still has same problem

Comment: Then use `scanf_s("%s",a[i] .manufacturersID,sizeof(a[i].manufacturersID));` and `scanf_s("%s",a[i].polarity,sizeof(a[i].polarity));`

Comment: @CoolGuy thanks man the ID and polarity is working now! why do you add size of, also same problem happen for the last 3 as well(i tried add size of)

Comment: Last three should be `scanf_s("%f",&a[i] .power)` , `scanf_s("%f",&a[i] .gain);` , `scanf_s("%i",&a[i] .stock);` and remove `\n` from the first `scanf_s`

Comment: @thank you so much man:)) all fixed

Comment: Remove `\n` from the second `scanf_s`, not the first one. The first dosen't have it... My mistake

Comment: @yoloXswag , I've added an answer now....

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from [the documentation of `scanf_s`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx),

> **Remarks:**
>
> [...]
>
> Unlike `scanf` and `wscanf`, `scanf_s` and `wscanf_s` require the buffer size to be specified for all input parameters of type `c`, `C`, `s`, `S`, or string control sets that are enclosed in `[]`. The buffer size in characters is passed as an additional parameter immediately following the pointer to the buffer or variable.

So, the `scanf_s`s:

```
scanf_s("%s",a[i].manufacturersID);
scanf_s("%s",a[i].polarity);
```

need a third argument specifing the buffer size as mentioned in the above quote. So, use

```
scanf_s("%s",a[i].manufacturersID,sizeof(a[i].manufacturersID));
scanf_s("%s",a[i].polarity,sizeof(a[i].polarity));
```

or

```
scanf_s("%s",a[i].manufacturersID,_countof(a[i].manufacturersID));
scanf_s("%s",a[i].polarity,_countof(a[i].polarity));
```

There are other errors too. These:

```
scanf_s("%f",a[i].power);
scanf_s("%f",a[i].gain);
scanf_s("%i",a[i].stock);
```

needs to be

```
scanf_s("%f",&a[i].power);
scanf_s("%f",&a[i].gain);
scanf_s("%i",&a[i].stock);
```

as the `%f` and `%i` expects a `float*` and `int*` respectively, and not a `float` and `int`.

As for why the first two `scanf_s` did not require a `&`, because ,in C, array names "decay" to a pointer to its first element. `a[i].manufacturersID` and `a[i].polarity` are arrays and the "decay" automatically happens.

You should also remove the `\n` from

```
scanf_s("%i\n", &total);
```

because `\n` is considered as a whitespace character and this character will discard any number of whitespace characters including none **until the first non-whitespace character** as specified in the C11 standard:

> **7.21.6.2 The fscanf function**
>
> [...]
>
> 5. A directive composed of white-space character(s) is executed by reading input up to the first non-white-space character (which remains unread), or until no more characters can be read. The directive never fails.